# View cmyk color code in pdf with linux

Tags: linux, pdf

I am currently working on some software which need to output cmyk pdf files. (I use Pdfclown which is a java pdf generating library for this).

I think my software is working correctly but to confirm that the colors are correct and as expected, I would like some software which can show me the cmyk color values in my output pdf file. Does anyone know any linux software which can do this?

Comment: If you use GIMP, you can get RGB values of any point on screen (even without taking an screenshot), And I think there is a CMYK plugin for gimp (written by Adobe), and if you install that you can get CMYK values too. If I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Do you have a link to that plugin? The only one I could find was http://cue.yellowmagic.info/softwares/separate-plus/index.html which as far as I can see don't support import/working with cmyk files. (It looks like it works in rgb, and then export to cmyk in the end).

Comment: @MTilsted, you want a tuple for every point in the image saying what its RGB is?

Comment: No, I want a tuple for each point saying if the color is a cmyk color, and if it is, I need to know the cmyk color code as saved in the document. The pdf files I generate contains cmyk colors not rbg. What I need is a manual way to read the pdf file, so I for example can verify that the black color I use in some of the graphics really is encoded/saved as the cmyk color (0,0,0,1) in the pdf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only check tool I know is Adobe Preflight, part of Adobe Acrobat Professional package, which unfortunately is only available under Windows. If you know anybody that has it, use Preview in Preflight to verify the colors used.

Here are some remarks that may pertain.

Any pdf viewed on the screen must convert to RGB, so that's not the way to go.

Most JPG images are in RGB, so better not use any of these.
TIFF can be in CMYK.

Printeries convert to CMYK before printing, so you should check that your range of colors can be adequately presented.

Comment: So I guess I will just give up, or visit a graphics designer with Preflight installed. I thought about installing it together with windows on a vm, but it cost €650 which is far to much just to see some color codes

Comment: I downloaded a copy of "Adobe Acrobat pro X" which seems to include preflight, but I can't seem to find a feature in preflight which would give me the color of a specific point in the pdf file. It can show all the objects in the pdf file, but it is rather difficult to map objects to what is shown on the screen.

Comment: This might help : [Diving into Acrobat: Examine and Fix PDF Files with Acrobat Preflight](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1756414).

Comment: Not really. It just shows me where preflight is. I already know that. But it seems that preflight can't give cmyk colors for a specific point in the preview

Comment: I haven't seen preflight in Acrobat, but it should be able to give  the summary for the page.

Comment: And the obvious solution to my problem was photoshop. Photoshop can open pdf files in cmyk and then show the real cmyk colors. So obvious in retrospect.

Comment: "JPG images are alwys in RGB, so better not use any of these"
Nope. Jpeg support CMYK.

Comment: @Thayne: The Jpeg standard is extensible and can in theory support any color space, especially RGB, grayscale, YCbCr and CMYK. In practice, using an uncommon color space, one may encounter a problem with some viewers on some platforms.

Comment: @harrymc It is true that not all viewers work well with CMYK jpegs, but it is not the case that "JPG images are always in RGB" since there are definitely jpeg files with non-RGB color spaces. And the same problem exists for TIFF files. In fact as far as I know JPEG is the only image format that can be embedded directly in a PDF without having to convert to a raw raster array.

Comment: @Thayne: Since you insist, I changed "always" to "most".